# Xamarin Forms iOS Device won't receive Push from Urban Airship

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, urbanairship.com

I have an Xamarin Forms app that I can't get push notifications to work in iOS.  They are working fine in Android. The device is properly registering with Urban Airship using their SDK v4.1.0. I am able to get a ChannelId and a Device Token.  When I send a push out on the Dev channel, the Android device gets the notification, but the iOS device does not.  In Urban Airship, the Full Message Report shows that the message was delivered to the Android device and both iOS devices I have tested this on.  I am sure that I am missing something small, but I can't figure out what it is.  Below is the source from the App Delegate as reference.  It is pretty straight forward from the examples I have seen.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using UrbanAirship;

namespace -----------.Mobile.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

            UAConfig config = new UrbanAirship.UAConfig();
            config.DevelopmentAppKey = "----------------------";
            config.DevelopmentAppSecret = "----------------------";
            config.ProductionAppKey = "----------------------";
            config.ProductionAppSecret = "----------------------";

#if DEBUG
            config.InProduction = false;
#else
            config.InProduction = true
#endif
            UAirship.TakeOff(config);
            UAirship.Push.UserPushNotificationsEnabled = true;
            UAirship.Push.ChannelTagRegistrationEnabled = true;

            // Write the ChannelId for reference later.

            Guid urbanAirshipChannelId;
            UrbanAirshipData uaData = new UrbanAirshipData();
            if (Guid.TryParse(UAirship.Push.ChannelID, out urbanAirshipChannelId))
            {   
                uaData.UrbanAirshipChannelId = urbanAirshipChannelId;
                uaData.UrbanAirshipDeviceType = Common.Utilities.Enumerations.eUrbanAirshipDeviceType.iOS;
            }
            UAirship.Push.PushNotificationDelegate = PushReceived();


            LoadApplication(new App(uaData));

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }

        private UAPushNotificationDelegate PushReceived()
        {
            UAPushNotificationDelegate result = new UAPushNotificationDelegate();

            return result;
        }



    }
}
```

Any feedback or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The line `UAirship.Push.PushNotificationDelegate = PushReceived();`
, there is an issue with Urban Airship's delegates where they do not store a strong reference to the delegate - https://github.com/urbanairship/xamarin-component/issues/40

However that will not cause the device to not receive a push. By default if the app is in the foreground nothing will happen on push receive. In the background it will post a notification. You can modify that behavior by setting default foreground notification options on UAPush instance for iOS 10.

If you are still struggling to receive a push I would contact Urban Airships support or post an issue on the github. Full logs will be needed.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I have a question.  Is the expected behavior in iOS to be the following?  When an app is running the foreground and a push is received, that device will not notify the user, but the notification will be listed with other notifications?  Also, you mentioned that this can be changed in the UAPush Instance.

I have been watching the notification list when I try to push and don't seen anything. I think I may have to post an issue. I have contacted UA, but our customer's service level does not have support.

Comment: Apple assumed the app would handle the push and not post any notifications all the way up to iOS 10. Now they allow setting foreground presentation options. You can set the defaults here - http://docs.urbanairship.com/reference/libraries/ios/latest/Classes/UAPush.html#/c:objc(cs)UAPush(py)defaultPresentationOptions. They will probably have you post in the community forum but they are pretty quick to respond.

Comment: Thanks.  I will make that my next step.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: How would I get the full logs needed to post on Urban Airship.

Comment: Enable verbose logging by setting the log level in your airship config options. Then copy the console output. Make sure you do not post your app credentials or any private info.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was the fact that I was testing with the app in the foreground and iOS was not presenting the notification with the app running.  I had to add the following to get it work in the foreground and make a sound.

```
UAirship.Push.DefaultPresentationOptions = UserNotifications.UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert | UserNotifications.UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Sound;
```